# How to search patterns starts in one line and ends in other line?

Tags: linux

I am searching a pattern which starts from line 3 and ends in line 4 in my file, how to search these kind of patterns in linux

cat myfile.txt having text

```
you know who is super hero  
where they are  
super hero are born by birth,  
they are good for us.
```

grep -irls 'super hero are born by birth,they are good for us' *

Comment: What's your expected output?  What exactly do you want to match?

Comment: Hi @Tiw , I am expecting file name if it has the pattern  'Super hero are born by birth , \n  they are good' in any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If available for your system, `pcregrep` is simple to use:

```
pcregrep -M -irls 'super hero are born by birth,\nthey are good for us' *
```

`-M` enables multiline matching. `\n` matches newline character.

If it's possible that the quote may be broken into many lines at any point, then you can replace every occurrence of  (matches exactly one space) with `\s+` (matches one or more of any "whitespace" character):

```
pcregrep -M -irls 'super\s+hero\s+are\s+born\s+by\s+birth,\s+they\s+are\s+good\s+for\s+us' *
```

Comment: Hi @jhnc , how to know weather 'pcregrep' is available or not ? and i dont know weather the pattern is in two line or three lines

Comment: On debian/ubuntu/etc, you can install with `sudo apt install pcregrep` (or a gui equivalent). Other distributions will have their own package manager.

Comment: Hi @jhnc i don't know weather the pattern is in single line or multiple line, users will pass the pattern like "super hero are born by birth, they are good for us' and code need to search in files weather its in single line or multiple lines . If it is in single line then normal grep -irls 'pattern' * will give the result , but if not in single line then it wont give

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on regular expressions. Depends on how detailed a description you want. https://www.regex101.com seems to be a commonly recommended place to experiment

Comment: Thanks a lot @jhnc i will check that link

Comment: Its working for and am getting proper output thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep, try this:

```
grep -zPirls 'super hero are born by birth,[[:space:]]*they are good for us' *
```

GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='' '/super hero are born by birth,[[:space:]]*they are good for us/{print FILENAME}' *
```

Comment: This emulates `pcregrep` (which avoids having to install it separately). Using `-z`, while giving unambiguous output,  may be confusing in this case.

Comment: Sorry. I got mixed up with `-Z`. Apparently I'm the confused one.